# Can we feed external data to xDB?

Tags: xdb

For example Google Analytics, Adobe Analytics or any other data to make a consolidated data report from Sitecore xDB.

If it is feasible, is there any guide on how to feed in data in real time or automatically.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? do you want to pull analytics data from google as an example, store it to xDB and then somehow view it as a report in Sitecore?

Answer (score 6):

I think that what you want here is not actually feed data into xDB, but rather export data from xDB, Google Analytics and whatever other analytics you have, and combine it using an external BI tool so it can be analyzed as one set of data.

Assuming your other analytics tools already have options for exporting the data, you only need to export the xDB data.
This can be achieved with the upcoming xConnect API, which unfortunately is not yet available at this point (not until Sitecore 8.3).
It will provide you with an oData endpoint that can be used in tools like Tableau and Power BI where you can analyse them.

If you can't wait until 8.3 then there is a another way, although it's much less user-friendly, the Sitecore Experience Extractor: https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor

That tools allows you to extract data from xDB based on certain criteria which you can then load into an external BI tool, together with your other analytics data, in order to analyse it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.

I was asked from the business team if we can incorporate external analytics data from Adobe Analytics, Google Analytics or Mass emailing system to have a more accurate personalization in the site. 

Using BI can give insight from consolidated data as a report but not how the website interacting with users.

Answer (score 5):

Sitecore has released the Data Exchange Framework. This tool allows you to sync content from third party application. Example:

1. Read contacts from a CRM and create contacts in xDB
2. Update a contact in CRM using information from a contact in xDB
3. Create items in Sitecore that represent products in a catalog

So, you can easily use this tool to import your external data to your xDB. You only have to develop the different logic that requires to translate the data from the third party to the template of your new instance.

Here is the link where you can have the 2 released version:

V1.0: https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Data_Exchange_Framework/1x/Data_Exchange_Framework_10.aspx

V1.1: https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Data_Exchange_Framework/1x/Data_Exchange_Framework_11.aspx

From the links, Sitecore has already specified the released note, required documentation about the API and so on.

Comment: Thank you Hishaam for reply. Does it works with the analytics data as well? e.g. importing contact from CRM with data of click through and if they exit or complete the process for each people.

Comment: Yes, from the Sitecore documentation it says that importing contacts to xDB is available. It's just that the Data Exchange is new and there are still new features to be added