# How to Migrate google analytics data to sitecore analytics using Data exchange framework in sitecore 9.2

Tags: xdb, xconnect, data-exchange-framework

We have a requirement of migrating google analytics data into Sitecore analytics using Data Exchange Framework, I have google analytics data in .xlsx format. So How can I migrate these .xlsx format data into Sitecore xDB?

Comment: Seems to be similar of this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/can-we-feed-external-data-to-xdb

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, can you please share any blog for migrate google analytics data to sitecore xdb using data exchange framework ?

Comment: There is no proper blog but first, you should read about the basics of Data Exchange Framework then second Value Mapping of Sets of data from source property to targe property.